# Create Hive table with Phoenix handler throws NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.SecurityInfo

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, amazon-emr, apache-phoenix

I want to create hive table on top of phoenix table in emr.

I am facing a  `NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.SecurityInfo`

What I have done so far:

1. I followed the instructions from https://phoenix.apache.org/hive_storage_handler.html and added `phoenix-hive-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar` to `hive-env.sh` as well as in  `hive-site.xml` .
2. Restarted the hive service `systemctl restart hive-server2.service`
3. Restarted the metastore `systemctl restart hive-hcatalog-server.service`
4. Executed create table command from hue:

```html
create external table ext_table (
  i1 int,
  s1 string,
  f1 float,
  d1 decimal
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.phoenix.hive.PhoenixStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "phoenix.table.name" = "ext_table",
  "phoenix.zookeeper.quorum" = "localhost",
  "phoenix.zookeeper.znode.parent" = "/hbase",
  "phoenix.zookeeper.client.port" = "2181",
  "phoenix.rowkeys" = "i1",
  "phoenix.column.mapping" = "i1:i1, s1:s1, f1:f1, d1:d1"
);
```

Got an exception: `Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.SecurityInfo)`

I am using emr-6.1.0

HBase 2.2.5

Phoenix 5.0.0

Hive 3.1.2

Anybody has an idea what can be the issue?

### Update

I followed the advice from @leftjoin and used `ADD JAR` from hue to add phoenix-hive jar to classpath. Then I faced jar compatibility issue caused by phoenix hive connector that I use:
`phoenix-hive-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar`.

The newer versions of phoenix connectors are not archived into single bundle that could be downloaded from [phoenix website](https://phoenix.apache.org/download.html) . Instead
the connectors are located now in [github repo](https://github.com/apache/phoenix-connectors).

I built the new phoenix-hive connector (versions: Phoenix->5.1.0, Hive->3.1.2, Hbase->2.2) and used it to create the Hive table.

As a result I got another exception, which I am not able to fix:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/phoenix/compat/hbase/CompatSteppingSplitPolicy
```

I think it is still somehow connected to dependency issues. But no clue what is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround put jar into hdfs and execute `ADD JAR` command before create table and query:

```
ADD JAR hdfs://path/to/your/jar/phoenix-hive-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar;
```

Comment: thanks @leftjoin, I did it and now after executing create query getting the following error `Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/phoenix/util/QueryUtil` . Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @bstent This is not informative, better provide full exception message